# Recover partition table or MBR in EXT4 backup HD

Tags: partition, ext4, data-recovery

I have a external USB HD for backup formated with EXT4.

When I turned it on, it made some weird noise and I was unable to connect to it with ubuntu. Nautilus said unable to mount and many other errors.

I can see the HD with TestDisk but it was unable to find the partition.

PhotoRec is recovering the files right now. I need mostly image files.

But it will download all messed up and mixed up.

I'd like to try to recover the partition table after the data recovery is done.

Is there a way to recover?

TestDisk output:

> Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
>
> ```
> Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
> ```
>
> Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, Enter: to continue

Regards

Answer (score 1):

For the `ext4` partition you have superblocks stored at other positions, so you can (try to) mount it by specifying some alternate superblocks. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408692 and for finding where the superblocks could be you can use `mke2fs -n` (do not forget the `-n` as this flag makes `mke2fs` not really write any data).

Do you remember maybe how it was partitioned? Number of partitions?
Have you tried the deeper search option of TestDisk? You may have luck with the `gpart` tool or the option `rescue` in `parted`.

Since your hardware may be dying you should probably first start by making a full lowlevel copy of it, using `ddrescue` or equivalent.

Comment: It had only 1 partition. Deeper search of TestDisk gave me nothing.

After the photorec is done I'll try the gpart tool and come back here.

Comment: I was able to recover the files with photorec but directories and filenames are all messed up.

option rescue in parted didnt helped.

gpart /dev/sdf is scanning for quite some time. After its done I will try something else.

(parted) rescue                                                           
Start? 1
End? 1000000                                                              
(parted)

Comment: Try to search for bytes 0x53 0xEF at beginning of the disk. They should be on position 1080-1081 of any ext2/3/4 partition. See https://superuser.com/a/239114/693623

Comment: should I use "1080-1081" at start? or "1080" or "1081"? I tried both but didn't work. What shoud I use at the end?  gpart /dev/sdf took almost 24 hs but guessed no usefull results